# coredns container is getting restarted repeatedly in the kubernetes worker node

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster with 1 master node and 2 worker nodes. I have installed flannel as network plugin. The coredns pods inside the worker node keeps on going to CrashLoopBackOff state and then to running state. does anyone know what could be the reason.

if YES, please helm me with the solution

logs:

```
E0820 08:27:52.824620       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:320: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0820 08:27:52.824913       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:315: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
E0820 08:27:54.825587       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:313: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0820 08:27:54.827941       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:320: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
E0820 08:27:56.827227       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:313: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
E0820 08:27:58.831233       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:313: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
2018/08/20 08:27:59 [INFO] SIGTERM: Shutting down servers then terminating
E0820 08:28:00.839084       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:315: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
E0820 08:28:02.847262       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:320: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
```

Comment: Could you provide logs for the Coredns Pod and its containers: `kubectl logs <coreds-pod-name>` and `kubectl describe <coreds-pod-name>`

Comment: hi,

thanks for your reply...i could resolve this problem with calico by changing my network but i am again facing the same issue with flannel plugin

Comment: seems like you have some problems with the internal Kubernetes network. Try to check, is IP subnet `10.96.0.1` which used by Coredns Pod the same as you have configured in your Pod network

Comment: same problem here :(  I will switch to other network add-on also :(

Comment: Could you kindly share your Kubernetes version and could you also share your flannel yaml file ?

Comment: kubernetes version is 1.18.4